# How can i check if system clock is sync or not in twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I'm new in twitter4j and i got this

`401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.`

I want to know how can i check system clock is sync or not ? is there a relation between system clock and twitter server ?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Does it have an NTP library / function that you can call?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 .yes i have ntp

Comment: On the command line, run `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` to update your clock.

Comment: Thanks ,it worked successfully